# Plastic SCM full distributed mode license

Tags: licensing, distribute, plasticscm

If I can use full distribute mode with local server. Can I use this same license from remote server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Plastic SCM server requires his own license. If you are working distributed, please contact us at support at codicesoftware dot com and we will generate a new license in your user account for that purpose.